# How to access modules from parent or sibling folder modules?

Tags: module, rust

I am trying to access modules from the `parser.rs` and `another.rs` in the `solve.rs`. How to include those modules and use the "`use` statements"? If that is not possible what should be the code structure?

Here is the application folder tree:

```
app/src
--- main.rs
--- another.rs
--- mod.rs
--- parser/
-------- parser.rs
-------- mod.rs
--- solver/
-------- solve.rs
-------- mod.rs
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first option is absolute paths:

```rust
use crate::parser::Whatever;
use crate::solver::Another;
```

`crate` here is a keyword representing the crate root.

You can also use relative paths for advanced scenarios. Both solutions are discussed very nicely in the relevant [Rust Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html)

Also, don't forget that you need to make the modules public. They will be private by default and not accessible from parents or siblings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was still not able to refer to the objects. Then I tried this: "use project_name::parser::Whatever;" This worked.

Answer (score 1):

To access `parser/parser.rs` and `another.rs` from anywhere in your crate, you can use absolute paths (here I am also using [nested paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#using-nested-paths-to-clean-up-large-use-lists), which is not required but makes the structure of modules more clear):

```rust
use crate::{
    parser::parser,
    another,
};
```

You can also use relative paths with `super`, which refers to the parent module. More information is avaiable in [@Ishmaeel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56680458/6714194).

---

Regarding your code structure, it seems a little strange why you have `mod.rs` (not wrong, but just strange, especially `0`; you can totally leave `1` and `2` if you like it, but `0` might confuse you):

```
app/src
    main.rs
    another.rs
    mod.rs        // 0
    parser/
        parser.rs
        mod.rs    // 1
    solver/
        solve.rs
        mod.rs    // 2
```

- **Regarding `1` and `2`:**

  `mod.rs` was used in the 2015 edition for being able to create nested modules, but is no longer needed [in the 2018 edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) (assuming that you are using the currently newest and default for cargo 2018 edition, see [What are editions?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/editions/index.html)):

  > A `foo.rs` and `foo/` subdirectory may coexist; `mod.rs` is no longer needed when placing submodules in a subdirectory.
- **Regarding `0`:**

  The module you are defining via this is actually named `mod` (not `src` as you may have expected, though I'm not sure at all what you expected here), I'm unsure if you meant to do that. However if you did, there is still a way to access it via [`r#` - raw identifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/raw-identifiers.html), available since Rust 1.30:

  ```rust
  use crate::r#mod;
  ```

  If you don't want to write `r#mod` all over the place, you can use `as` like this:

  ```rust
  use crate::r#mod as new_name;
  ```

  Then you can refer to the module via `new_name`.